# What size mains cable do I need?

Tags: mains, cables

AC230V with 720W load. Can I get away with 0.75mm 3 core flex with a 5amp fuse or would I be better off with 1.5mm?

Comment: Hi! What have you researched so far? Also: what does "can I get away" mean? Under which country's code, or under what acceptable cost/heatup/margin/... assumption?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry that's probably a bit UK slang, "Can I get away with.." = "Will this be okay?". 

The 0.75mm 3 core is rated at 6amps so in theory it should be okay. But is it better practice to go a size up? 1.15mm is rated at 16amps.

Comment: "Will this be OK" isn't any better; OK is a very stretchable term. The whole point of ratings is that they guarantee a specific performance or law conformance under specific conditions. Since we neither know your specific conditions nor the specific performance you need (see my first comment), we can't help you :(

Comment: @S7ewie: You've asked your question on Electrical Engineering rather that DIY so we expect questions to be much more rigorous. To decide on suitability of a particular cable we would need to know not only the load but the cable length and maximum allowable voltage drop which would be determined by the minimum supply voltage at the supply and the minimum operating voltage of the equipment being powered. Can you see why your question can't be answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the ratings ...

0.75 mm2 three core overall insulated cable is rated at 6A for domestic use. Protecting it with a 5 A fuse is therefore compliant with the ratings.

720 W is roughly 3 A, which is less than the fuse rating and the cable rating.

If you're using it in a domestic setting, so normal room temperature ambient, then it looks like you're good.

if you're running it through a hot or hazardous ambient, then probably not.